# Ways to have lots of blocks on a site which is easy to manage

Tags: views, blocks, 7

I am building a new site and the client has about 400 pages under about 5 main categories. Each of these 5 sub-categories has further sub-categories.

My client want to put a block onto each page which has unique content, which is editable.

Let's say that the block is pulling in the content type 'news'. This would be about 400 (ish) blocks - if done just through the blocks UI.

I know about context and view relationships (although not a great deal), but I was wondering if there was anyone out there who had thought on the very best way to approach this idea.

What ways are there to curate this content and make it easy for the client to find what they want to edit?

Is there a whay which has worked for you to go about this set-up, something that experience shows is a good idea, that I might not have thought of?

Comment: Consider removing "best" and asking just for ways to do it. There hardly ever is clearly "best" solutions, and votes will show what people here sees as best anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Nodeblock module](https://drupal.org/project/nodeblock) - create a content type named "block", and then you can manage edit permissions like with any other node, using modules you want. It'll also support fields, translations et cetera. You can use taxonomy to keep track of what is where.

Answer (score 1):

You can Create a new field in your content type(lets assume TEST_CONTENT) say `Extra Text` and set *FIELD TYPE* to 'Long Text And Summary'. Yow will need [Panels](https://drupal.org/project/panels) and [Pages](https://drupal.org/project/panels) module to be installed on your machine.

You can implement it using **node view** .If you don't know how to use it , then

- Go to Structure->Pages
- Enable `Node View "node_view"` (if not enabled)
- Edit it And add a new variant (link on top right side)
  [image: Add Variant]
- Give it a title and check the Selection Rules checkbox and click on CREATE VARIANT button nad in Selection Rule Phase Select `Node:Bundle` from drop down field and click Add.
- Now Check the `TEST_CONTENT' Content type..[image: Select Content type].
- Save and continue. Then Choose the layout you want for each node to be and Continue. Keep Continuing until u land on Panel Content phase.
- Now each region of your panel page on top left corner you will find a cogwheel . Click on it and click on add content.
- Select `Node (content)' and form lsit on right select the field '(Extra Filed)'.[image]
- Save and you are have your customised node view.

You can add any text for the specific node ..it is more easy to maintain than creating a block or snippet.

If You Have Custom panel page for each page of your website than you are left with no other choice than creating block for each page.

Answer (score 0):

If u wish to add a static content to your site such as a block which would display same content for every page then you can use the **[snippet module](https://drupal.org/project/snippet)**.